# Не работает скрипт прыжка на сенсорной кнопке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал вот такой вот скрипт для прыжка по нажатию кнопки, почему то не работает, вот и ломаю голову что не так, заменить функцию Jump() на нажатие клавише в условие if, то все работает нормально`

```
public void Jump()
{

    if( isGrounded  )
    {
      anim.SetTrigger("jump");
      anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JumpForce);
        
   }
 else
   {
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
   }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну в вашем коде нигде не используется метод Jump. Отлавливайте нажатие кнопки прыжка и если она нажата делайте:

```
Jump();
```

Comment: я вызываю эту функцию через нажатие кнопки OnClick()

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли поставить функцию Jump на OnClick в кнопке.